# Is the function for the Weak Goldbach Conjecture an increasing function?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

### Premise

There is a function used to count the number of ways a given odd integer larger than 5 can be written as the sum of three prime numbers.
I have seen the function ($f_{3}$) expressed as the following in papers (or [discussions](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/heuristic-limitations-of-the-circle-method/)) for the [Weak Goldbach Conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture).

$$
f_{3}(x) = \int_{R/Z} S(x,\, \alpha) e(-x\alpha) \, d\alpha
$$
$$
e(\theta) := e^{2\pi i \theta}
$$
$$
S(x,\, \alpha) := \sum_{p \leq x} e(\alpha p)
$$

### Question

I had been looking at this function and wanting to understand its characteristics.
Is this function an increasing function?

Meaning, is the following true?

$$
f_{3}(x+2) - f_{3}(x) \geq 0
$$

### Thoughts

I feel like it is an increasing function because the function $S$ either has the same number of primes/terms or more.
But, it looks like $e(-x\alpha)$ could imply that the function could be decreasing or at least not be an increasing function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f_{3}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}} S(x, \alpha)^3 e(-x\alpha) \, d\alpha$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://oeis.org/A054860 gives "Number of ways of writing $2n+1$ as $p + q + r$ where $p, q, r$ are primes with $p \le q \le r$." It starts $0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 12, 13, 12, 15, 16$, so you can see it's not an increasing function. E.g., $f(17)=4$ but $f(19)=3$.

Answer (score 2):

For odd $x$, it is known due to I. M. Vinogradov that for odd $x\ge7$ we have

$$
f_3(x)={x^2\over2\log^3x}\prod_{p|x}\left(1-{1\over(p-1)^2}\right)\prod_{p\nmid x}\left(1+{1\over(p-1)^3}\right)+O\left(x^2\over\log^4x\right).
$$

From the infinite product factors, it is certain that $f_3(x)$ cannot be monotonic for large $x$ either.